# Grails fails to run-app

Tags: grails, command

using windows 7 , Grails 2.3.7, java 1.7 (Oracle) .. My app used to run  via run-app now it simply wont run .. no grails script commands are working (clean , compile ..).  Its quite a large app. I recreated the app (created another application and migrated all the code to it) and it was working fine - then it stopped with the same problem as previously ..

```
Error executing script Clean: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1 (NOTE: Stack trace has been    filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at Clean.run(Clean.groovy:25)
at Clean$run.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
... 17 more
```

I've looked in .grails.2.3.7 and cleared ALL versions of .slcache I could find and it still wont run  ..  Any ideas  ??  .. Also tried importing as an existing project using Intellij and still nothing ..

Answer (score 3):

Deleted a scriptCache folder I found under `<app-name>/target/projects/<project-name>/work`. Ran `grails clean`  and back in business!